# Add Custom Fields After Page Title

Tags: custom-field

I want to add my custom fields after the page title when you view it on the site.  How do I do this?

PAGE TITLE
[CUSTOM FIELDS HERE]

PAGE CONTENT

Answer (score 1):

Use [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) in the theme template you want to modify. Like so...

```
<h1>If This Were Your Page Title</h1>
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Your Custom Field Name', true); ?>
```

Easy peasy. :-)

Comment: I wish it was, but I'm a dope.  Can i add my meta to my theme's page.php?  and Where?  This is some of the code that's in the file: <?php global $theme; get_header();?>

   
<div id="main">

        <?php $theme->hook('main_before');?>

        <div id="content">

            <?php $theme->hook('content_before'); ?>

Comment: Check the link I provided for get_post_meta(), which explains it in detail. You can use the function anywhere, and it just needs a post id, the name of your custom field, and whether you want a value or array (true returns a single value, false returns an array). get_the_ID() can be used in just about any page template file (home.php, index.php, single.php, page.php, etc).

Comment: can i add the meta after a theme hook? such as title_after?